# PowerShell : Renaming bulk files but can't find the correct date: LastWriteTime vs CreationTime vs?

Tags: powershell

[Screenshot / List of files with dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlU6R.png)

I am new to PowerShell. I have been digging around but cant seem to solve this one on my own. Does anyone know how to extract the explorer file date? (The first date in the screenshot).

LastWriteTime and CreationTime are not using the date I am after. Example below of what I have tried.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter * -Recurse | %{$date = ($_.LastWriteTime).ToString("yyyyMMdd"); Rename-Item $_ -newname "$date - $_"}

Get-ChildItem -Filter * -Recurse | %{$date = ($_.CreationTime).ToString("yyyyMMdd"); Rename-Item $_ -newname "$date - $_"}
```

Comment: that `date` seems to be one that is grabbed from any of several more specific date sources. for some items [like mp3 files], it seems to come from "last modified". for jpg files it seems to come from an internal "date taken" value _if that file has such_ - otherwise it seems to come from the same "last modified" filesystem value.

Comment: This date that is listed in Explorer is probably "Last Accessed Date".

Comment: Looks like your three relevant attributes are CreationTime, LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime.  Are you saying one of these three is not the date you're after?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would try to place your command into a variable, for instance:

```
$var = Get-ChildItem -Filter * -Recurse
```

Directly from the shell, you can now use a pipe from this variable to list all the associated properties and methods while filtering the output for the specific date property you are searching for:

```
$var | Get-Member | ? {$_.definition -match "date"}
```

Comment: Hi did try the LastAccessTime as well but it also returns the incorrect date. "20210509" for all the files.